# MFMailComposeViewController in other languages?

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

**Does MFMailComposeViewController come only in English!?**

I am toying around with the idea of using MFMailComposeViewController to handle sending email from my app but I need it to conform to the language environments of devices set to languages other than english. Is it possible to set MFMailComposeViewController to other languages? Even if I set my device's language to, say, japanese, the MFMailComposeViewController's To:, From:, Subject:, portions remain in english. **How does one change the language of MFMailComposeViewController?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MFMailComposeViewController` will display in the language the application is translated into rather than the language the user has selected; this keeps the text within the application consistent. Add a language project for the language you are targeting and the composer view will adopt that language.

The Done button on the keyboard, the Delete button that shows when a `UITableViewCell` is swiped and other built-in views behave similarly.

Comment: Can you give me some hints on how to add a "language project"?

Comment: This guide explains it better than I could: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/11/localizing-iphone-apps.html I think this is something Apple should make easier in the next SDK update :)

Comment: Yes this helped greatly. I created a language project and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Even with MonoTouch and the whole application localized with .NET resx, I had to add [en|fr|de].lproj only to have the MFMailComposeViewController happy. Thanks.