# Localized version of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

we are making a finnish language app and it seems that the MFMailComposeViewController isn't localized. It doesn't look very professional if some part of the app is in english. Anyway to get a localized version?

Answer (score 1):

See prior post:

[MFMailComposeViewController in other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321281/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-other-languages)