# Translating text on buttons when using mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How is it possible to change the title of the UIBarButtonItem's when using mfmailcomposeviewcontroller? I don't want the text "cancel"/"send" and I also do not need the save/delete draft option which prompt the user when he/she taps "cancel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. MFMailComposeViewController is not customizable.

You can change the Development Region in your Info.plist so that your system buttons will be translated, or add translations in your app and the system buttons will be translated to the user's selected language.

Note: This is probably a duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321281/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-other-languages)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have set it with a system item "style" `UIBarButtonSystemItem`.

You have these to use, or use a custom one:

- UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
  UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo,        //   iOS 3.0 and later
  UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo,        //   iOS 3.0 and later
  UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl,    //   iOS 4.0 and later

---

Oh i did not see the "Translating" from the title..

Comment: And you can't change the style of the buttons on the MFMailComposeViewController, that's not a custom UINavigationBar