# Whats the behavior of MFMailComposer language in iOS7 and iOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, localization, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

[MFMailComposeViewController in other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321281/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-other-languages)

Whats the behavior of MFMailComposer language in iOS7 and iOS8?

I changed the language inside my application but the MFMailComposer stays the same with the language in the device settings (iOS8).

Is this the expected behavior in iOS 8?

If yes, how do you translate the text?

NSLocalizedString coming from Localizable.strings(specific language) doesn't seem to affect MFMailComposer in my case.

Comment: Could you add more detail about what you tried? This should be working in iOS 7/8 same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the localized strings to your project so the app can get the strings and change them for the specific language you selected. If you won't have another language, it will choose the basic english strings for presentation.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321570/1141395)

Comment: Sorry I meant that using Localizable.strings doesn't affect the MFMailComposer